# Advanced WordPress plugin activation detection

Tags: wordpress, activation, wordpress-hook

I'm testing the plugin activation detection because something went wrong in my plugin. I discovered the problem, but didn't understand it:

I'm trying to check for plugins activation (others and my own) but inside an WordPress hook (`init`, for instance)

In the first example i will listen to the "Hello Dolly" plugin activation:

```
add_action('init', function(){
    register_activation_hook('hello.php', function(){
        echo 'Hello was activated.';
    });
    do_action('wordpress_initialized');
});

add_action('wordpress_initialized', function(){
    register_activation_hook('hello.php', function(){
        echo 'Hello is not allowed.';
        die;
    });
});
```

What i'm doing is:

1. listening to the `init` hook
2. Inside it, listening to the `hello.php` plugin activation to say it was activated.
3. Inside the init hook, triggering an custom hook to say wordpress is loaded
4. Outside, i wait for this another custom hook and then listen to the hello activation
5. When activated, i block the activation saying it's not allowed.

This is an example, and it works, when the plugin i'm listening is another plugin.

**The problem:** If i apply this code to listen MY plugin, it will not work. (content below is inside `myplugin.php`)

```
add_action('init', function(){
    register_activation_hook('myplugin.php', function(){
        echo 'myplugin was activated.';
    });
    do_action('wordpress_initialized');
});

add_action('wordpress_initialized', function(){
    register_activation_hook('myplugin.php', function(){
        echo 'myplugin is not allowed.';
        die;
    });
});
```

And this happens because, i wait until the init hook to register the activation hook... If i register the activation hook outside any hook, it will work.

But there is more.

If i trigger an custom action inside the activation hook, this action can be listen.

```
register_activation_hook('myplugin.php', function(){
    echo 'myplugin was activated.';
    do_action('myplugin_activate');
});

add_action('myplugin_activate', function(){
    echo 'myplugin is not allowed.';
    die;
});
```

So there is the problem and there is the solution, but what i don't know is WHY, why i can listen to other plugins activation, but can't listen to my own this way? It's because the activation process? I read about this in the docs and an redirection happens, how this affect the working flow?

**---EDIT---**

The last example isn't exactly an solution. What i need is add an listener to my own plugin inside the init hook like this:

```
add_action('init', function (){
    add_action('myplugin_activate', function(){
        echo 'myplugin is not allowed.';
        die;
    });
});
```